# tcl tk rerun application without restarting interpreter

Tags: tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am a newcomer to tcl/tk and need to run a script in cadence's encounter. To do so I source my file in the provided interpreter and call my function. On the first run it works fine. However once I close my main window created with Tk, and try to rerun my method it tells me that it can't invoke the `wm` command since the application has been destroyed. How can I rerun the script without restarting the tcl interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing the main window is the problem, it puts Tk into a non recoverable state that can only be followed by an exit.

Try binding to the WM_DELETE message and just hide/iconify the main window '.' or use an extra toplevel window instead of the default '.' window.

Depending on your script you might need to do a few more things, as some widgets/names might already exists when running twice.

Comment: is there a possibility to create a childinterpreter and run within that? So that I go create child interpreter, run, delete child? After reading that Tk is not recoverable I hope ther is a solution like this. I would need some guidance on that thought, currently it complains (in the child interpreter) that the package Tk can't be found, the parent interpreter does not complain and runs fine though.

Comment: @ted, yes, you can create child interp.

Comment: A child interpreter might help, but reloading Tk in it doesn't help you if the main toplevel has been destroyed.

Comment: even if I use the main part just as a base and load TK ONLY and ALWAYS in the child?

Comment: You can load Tk in the parent but withdraw `.` and never make use of it. That'll work just fine. Just remember to get your logic for _actually_ exiting the application correct. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I used to use something like this, exposed in a debug menu: (warning not tested!)

```
proc Restart {} {
   foreach w [winfo children .] {
       destroy $w
   }
   source [info script]
}
```

which (hopefully) destroys all the child widgets and then recreates them by resourcing the script, assuming that's what the current script does.

but this will depend on how you are building your windows in the first place as schlenk suggests

Comment: Hello. This is what I found with this function however the idea is generally good and works.
1- it's better to ` set script_name [info script] `  from the very start of the script to get that info as a global variable. so you can call it any time.

2- also all kinds of variables of the script must be zeroed/cleared out/ reset to empty so you can have a fresh start.